# Regular expression to remove digits and '-' and get all other data replacing newline with @#

Tags: sql-server, regex

> 45378 - Colonoscopy, diagnostic (separate procedure)
>
> 45331 - Flexi Sigmoidoscopy with biopsy
>
> 45378 - Colonoscopy, diagnostic (separate procedure)
>
> 45331 - Flexi Sigmoidoscopy with biopsy
>
> 45378 - Colonoscopy, diagnostic (separate procedure)
>
> 45331 - Flexi Sigmoidoscopy with biopsy

How to get the above text like below in sql server

```
@# Colonoscopy, diagnostic (separate procedure) 
@# Flexi Sigmoidoscopy with biopsy 
@# Colonoscopy, diagnostic (separate procedure) 
@# Flexi Sigmoidoscopy with biopsy 
@# Colonoscopy, diagnostic (separate procedure) 
@# Flexi Sigmoidoscopy with biopsy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example came up with the following but the length of the numeric value is hardcoded in the PATINDEX and STUFF usage:

```
 DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @Text = '45378 - Colonoscopy, diagnostic (separate procedure) 45331 - Flexi Sigmoidoscopy with biopsy 45378 - Colonoscopy, diagnostic (separate procedure) 45331 - Flexi Sigmoidoscopy with biopsy 45378 - Colonoscopy, diagnostic (separate procedure) 45331 - Flexi Sigmoidoscopy with biopsy'

 WHILE (PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @Text) > 0)
 BEGIN
        SET @Text = STUFF(@Text, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @Text), 5, '@#')
 END

 SELECT @Text
```